# How do I get cookies in react js using react-cookie?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-cookie

The react-cookie docs have this example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import NameForm from './NameForm';
class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const { cookies } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      name: cookies.get('name') || 'Ben'
    };
  }

  handleNameChange(name) {
    const { cookies } = this.props;

    cookies.set('name', name, { path: '/' });
    this.setState({ name });
  }
```

Can I use cookies.get without using componentWillMount?

Answer (score 4):

There is a little miss use of life-cycle hooks there.

You should be giving initial value to `state` on class constructor.

e.g.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.cookies.get('name') || 'Ben',
    }
  }
...
```

or if you use newer ES7 syntax just

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
      name: this.props.cookies.get('name') || 'Ben',
    }
...
```

`constructor` -function is not required on lower example

`componentWillMount` life-cycle will also be deprecated in upcoming React releases so I would recommend to avoid using it.

Replacement for it is accordingly

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   return {username: nextProps.username}
}
```

See difference here, we return normal `Object` which then get's passed to Components state. So in here `username` would be get passed to `state`.

Comment: how do I use it outside of a component